# How to verify email address with regex and CSML

Tags: regex, email, chatbot

I would like to validate email address from user giving information to my chatbot.
Is there a simple way to deny unexpected symbols with regular expressions and CSML?

Here's my current code:

```
askEmail:
say "Thank you {{firstname}}"
say "What is your email address?"
hold
remember email = event
if (Find("@", in="email")) goto askCompany
else {
say "Please enter a real email address"
goto askEmail
}
```

I need to replace Find with a function using regexp and check all unexpected symbols.

Comment: How do you define a valid email address ? can it end with .com, .gov.uk etc., Say this is an example of regex `[\w_]+@[A-Za-z]+(?:\.[A-Za-z]+)+`

Comment: It again depends on which regex engine is used. Based on that we may have to change the syntax

Comment: It looks like the interpreter is written in rust: https://github.com/CSML-by-Clevy/csml-engine

Comment: ok did you try the above ? Did you check their documentation on how to use regex

Comment: The best way to validate an email address is to send an email and check the return value. 
Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `contains_regex` [string method in CSML](https://docs.csml.dev/language/standard-library/string-methods#contains-string-contains_regex-string) that you can use to verify more complex rules than just "is there a @ in this string?".

It's quite hard to cover all possible valid email addresses with a regex (see https://emailregex.com), but let's just agree for your purpose that emails are in the general form of `"whatever@whatever.whatever"` where `"whatever"` is any string that does not contain any line break.

This is obviously not a 100% foolproof regex as it is a bit naive, but validating emails is still a **Hard Thing ®**. Good enough is usually good enough.

Here goes:

```
askEmail:
  say "Thank you {{firstname}}"
  say "What is your email address?"
  hold
  remember email = event
  if (email.contains_regex("^.+@.+\..+$")) goto askCompany
  else {
    say "Please enter a real email address"
    goto askEmail
  }
```

You can obviously tweak the regex to your liking!

Answer (score 1):

```js
emailPattern = /^([a-z\d]{1})([\w-\.!#$%&'*+\/=?\^`\{\|\}~"\(\),:;<>\[\\\]]){2,}([a-z\d]{1})@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}))$/i;

console.log('Regex test is: ', emailPattern.test('test@test.test'));
```

```
emailPattern = /^([a-z\d]{1})([\w-\.!#$%&'*+\/=?\^`\{\|\}~"\(\),:;<>\[\\\]]){2,}([a-z\d]{1})@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}))$/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Email Regular Expression Pattern

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)* @[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$;
```